# How to update a field in document in a firestore

Tags: c#, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to update a string field in specific document using Firebase Firestore for my android app but every method I see is while knowing the document refernce which I find difficult to find in my program.
Would like for some help for another method or help in finding the document refernce using a specific field value.
Thanks in advance.
(using C# btw)

```
private async Task<string> GetDocRefAsync(string userId)
        {
            Object obj = await FirestoreData.GetFirestore().Collection(DBConstants.FS_COLLECTION_USERS).
                    WhereEqualTo(DBConstants.FS_COLLECTION_USERS_USER_ID, userId).Get();
            QuerySnapshot snapshot = (QuerySnapshot)obj;
            if (snapshot.IsEmpty)
            {
                Log.Debug("UpdateGroupAsync", "userId: " + userId + " not found");
                return null;
            }
            string docRef = "";
            foreach (DocumentSnapshot item in snapshot.Documents)
            {
                //docRef = item.;
                
            }
            return docRef;
        }
```

Firstly ive tried to find the document ref using this code but dont have a function to get the ref even after getting the correct document.
the fourth line from the bottom is where I couldnt find it.

[database pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py2Dn.png)

```
this.groupCode = code;
                string strUserRef = GetDocRefAsync(userRef).ToString();
                DocumentReference docReference = database.Collection(DBConstants.FS_COLLECTION_USERS_GROUPS_CODE).Document(strUserRef);
                docReference.Update(DBConstants.FS_COLLECTION_USERS_GROUPS_CODE, groupCode);
```

Comment: So, you want to locate the document based on the value of one of its fields? Have you looked at using a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)?

Comment: I did but without sucsess, would you mind inform me with an exemple? @Tyler V

Comment: Show what you tried in the question and describe what happened.

Comment: @Tyler V Im sorry having trouble posting the code, not so familiar with stackoverflow

Comment: I dont know what I did wrong lol

Comment: @ Tyler V Fixed it

Comment: @ Tyler V I try to update the field "groupcode" with "userId" in hand. I have no acsess for the document Ref Ive circled in red.

Comment: @ Tyler V thats what I tried to do but for some reason the fun returned me wrong value.

Comment: @Tyler V Thanks so much for trying to help me, after all I manage to get the ref but still having problem with updating the field. Please look at the new code and tell me if I did something wrong there.

Comment: @Tyler V tried it and had a comipler error stating the fun do not exist. only Update() is showing for me.

Comment: Ok, maybe you have an old version of Firebase. What happens when you call Update then?

Comment: @Tyler V basically nothing, while debugging ran trough each line of code with no  errors but while looking at the db console the fun did nothing.

Comment: @Tyler V and im sorry about not being clear, bit frustrated with this proj and its getting pretty late where I am.

Comment: @Tyler V I did check

Comment: @TylerV oh you were right I didnt check corectly, how couldI convert it.(if possible at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the documents where a field has a given value, you can use a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#c). Then once the query returns, you can get documents IDs with the `.Id` field on each `DocumentShapshot` in the returned documents.

You will also need to add `await` for the returned value since it is an async method returning a `Task<string>` not returning a `string`.

```cs
private async Task<string> GetDocRefAsync(string userId) {
    CollectionReference usersRef = FirestoreData.GetFirestore().Collection(DBConstants.FS_COLLECTION_USERS);
    Query query = usersRef.WhereEqualTo(DBConstants.FS_COLLECTION_USERS_USER_ID, userId);

    // or GetSnapshotAsync depending on the version of firebase
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.Get();
       
    // Note: if it matches multiple documents this will just return
    // the ID of the first match
    foreach (DocumentSnapshot item in snapshot.Documents)
    {
        return item.Id;
    }

    Log.Debug("UpdateGroupAsync", "userId: " + userId + " not found");
    return null;
}
```

And you can use it like this to update a document (note that you were using a different collection here - probably by mistake).

```
string userDocId = await GetDocRefAsync(userId);

CollectionReference userCollection = database.Collection(DBConstants.FS_COLLECTION_USERS);
DocumentReference docReference = userCollection.Document(userDocId);

// or UpdateAsync depending on your version of firebase
docReference.Update(DBConstants.FS_COLLECTION_USERS_GROUPS_CODE, groupCode);
```

Comment: still having trouble updating, just running through the code and when Ive checked at the console no update